# Laptop Hangs after disconnection from usb hub (Arch Linux)

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm using Arch linux on a lenovo x1 nano, and have an external dock.  Is there a way to check if the computer hanging is a software issue or hardware issue?

New to arch, but not new to linux.

Thanks!

Comment: Put Lenovo hardware diagnostics on a bootable USB key and test hardware. If hardware tests pass, your issue is likely software.

Comment: Check logs? What are the symptoms of your hangs? Is this just a hypothetical question, or are you dealing with a an, specific problem? If you're being specific, please give more specific details of your issue.

Comment: Yes dealing with a specific issue.  Will try and  collect more information and review the logs first.  It's unfortunately intermittent